# Minimum number of points to win a football league

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, combinations

Let $n$ be the number of teams in a football league. $n$ is even. Each pair of teams plays each other $2$ times (home and away) during the season. There are $2(n-1)$ fixtures and in each fixture there are $n/2$ games, thus there is a total of $n(n-1)$ games in a season.

Assume each team gets $3$ points for a win, $1$ point for a draw and $0$ points for a loss.

What is the minimum number of points a team can get and win the title? What must happen?

My initial guess is that it's enough for the winning team to draw $2(n-1)-1$ games and win one, getting $2(n-1)+2=2n$ points, while $n-2$ other teams draw the entire season, getting $2(n-1)$ points each, and the remaining team draws all except the one with the winning team, getting $2(n-1)-1$ points. For instance, in the Premier League, where there are $20$ teams, it would be enough for a team to get $40$ points.

Is this correct, or is it possible to win it with fewer points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum possible score for a clear champion is $2n$ points.

The total number of points among the games is $2n(n-1)+m$, where $m$ is the number of games that do not end in a draw.

The average number of points is therefore at least $2(n-1)=2n-2$ so a clear victory can't possibly be achieved with fewer than $2n-1$ points.  The example in the question demonstrates that a clear victory can be achieved with $2n$ points, so it remains to show that no clear victory can be achieved with $2n-1$ points.

If Team $1$ scores exactly $2n-1$ points, then because a victory results in $2$ more points than a draw, Team $1$ must be involved in at least two games that aren't a draw.  But that means the total number of points to be divided among the $n$ teams must be at least $2n(n-1)+2$.  By hypothesis, Team $1$ accounts for only $2n-1$ of those points, so the remaining $2n(n-2)+3 = 2(n-1)^2+1$ points must be divided among the remaining $n-1$ teams, which means at least one of the remaining teams must have more than $2(n-1)=2n-2$ points, so at least one of the remaining teams must have at least $2n-1$ points and Team $1$ is not a clear victor.

Answer (score 0):

In the Premier League 38 points would be sufficient if all games were drawn but one team had been involved in more high-scoring draws than the others i.e. had the highest goals total.

In general it depends on the rules of a particular league.

Comment: I believe the intended question is whether it's possible to win outright (i.e., without resort to tiebreakers based on anything other than accumulated points) with $2n-1$ points.

Comment: "For instance, in the Premier League, where there are 20 teams, it would be enough for a team to get 40 points. Is this correct, or is it possible to win it with fewer points?"

Comment: I'm aware that your read of the question is literally correct.  I continue to believe that he's more interested in the mathematical analysis than in the arcana of tiebreakers across various soccer leagues.